# EL mandatory or can we use another property name?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views

Doing my best to learn BackboneJS. I was told that "el" is special. However, looking at the code below, looks like I can use any property name I like. For example:

```
MyEL : $('body')
```

then I'm going to use it this way

```
$(this.MyEL).append("<ul></ul>");
```

Am I violating if I don't use el? Am I breaking something?

```
(function($){
  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'), // el attaches to existing element
    myEL: $('body'), // myEL attaches to existing element

    events: {
      'click button#add': 'addItem'
    },
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

      this.counter = 0; // total number of items added thus far
      this.render();
    },

    // `render()` now introduces a button to add a new list item.
    render: function(){
    //  $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>Add list item</button>");
    //  $(this.el).append("<ul></ul>");

      $(this.myEL).append("<button id='add'>Add list item</button>");
      $(this.myEL).append("<ul></ul>");
    },

    // `addItem()`: Custom function called via `click` event above.
    addItem: function(){
      this.counter++;
      $('ul', this.el).append("<li>hello world"+this.counter+"</li>");
    }
  });

  var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Its all about connecting your view to the DOM. I'm not sure if your events for example will work without your `el` in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code, what you're doing is **extending** (`Backbone.View.extend({//options})`) the default backbone view object with whatever properties you wish to add. If you pass a property that exists by default in backbone view, it'll be overwritten with the value you pass.

By default all backbone views have an `el` property. If you don't explicitly pass it's value in options, backbone will create a `<div>` and assign it to the `el` property.

When you pass `el: $('body')` in the options, backbone will point the default `el` property to `<body>` and won't create a `<div>`.

By passing `myEL: $('body')` in the options, you've creating a property in the view object called `myEL` which points to `<body>` element, which in this case seems quite unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, that's the answer i was looking for! :)